# JavaFX 2 Automatic Column Width

Tags: javafx-2

I have a JavaFX 2 table that is displaying contact details for people, lets imagine there are three columns: first name, last name and email address. When my application starts it populates the table with several rows of data about the people already in the system.

The problem is that the column widths are all the same. Most of the time the first and last name is displayed in full but the email address is getting clipped. The user can double click the divider in the header to resize the column but that will become tedious quickly.

Once the table has been pre-populated I would like to programatically resize all the columns to display the data they contain but I can't figure out how to achieve this. I can see that I can call `col.setPrefWidth(x)` but that doesn't really help as I would have to guess the width.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If your total number of columns are pre-known. You can distribute the column widths among the tableview's width:

```
nameCol.prefWidthProperty().bind(personTable.widthProperty().divide(4)); // w * 1/4
surnameCol.prefWidthProperty().bind(personTable.widthProperty().divide(2)); // w * 1/2
emailCol.prefWidthProperty().bind(personTable.widthProperty().divide(4)); // w * 1/4
```

In this code, the width proportions of columns are kept in sync when the tableview is resized, so you don't need to do it manually. Also the `surnameCol` takes the half space of the tableview's width.

Answer (score 24):

This works for me in JavaFX 8

```
table.setColumnResizePolicy( TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY );
col1.setMaxWidth( 1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 50 ); // 50% width
col2.setMaxWidth( 1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 30 ); // 30% width
col3.setMaxWidth( 1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 20 ); // 20% width
```

In the other examples you have the problem, the vertical scrollbar width is ignored.

Comment: Where do you see that you can pass percents to setMaxWidth ?

Comment: Clever trick - big enough numbers so that proportional sizing down needs to be used to fit into the real size.

Comment: Thanks, using your technique now. Still I faced problems with the vertical scrollbar width. When enough items are added that the vertical scrollbar appeared immediately, it caused a little offset between the vertical TableView lines of header and rows. I was able to fix this by refreshing the TableView:
After `myTableView.setItems(myObservableList);` refresh the GUI (Graphical User Interface) by accessing the Application Thread with: line #1: `Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {` line #2: `@Override public void run() {` line #3: `myTableView.refresh();` line#4: `}});`

Answer (score 4):

As I use SceneBuider, I just define the MinWidth, and MaxWidth to some columns and to the main column I just define the PrefWidth to "USE_COMPUTED_SIZE"

Comment: The programmatic version of this is just `col.setPrefWidth(Control.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);`

Answer (score 3):

After 3 years, finally I found the solution, [javafx column in tableview auto fit size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650787/javafx-column-in-tableview-auto-fit-size)

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin;
import javafx.scene.control.Skin;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class GUIUtils {
    private static Method columnToFitMethod;

    static {
        try {
            columnToFitMethod = TableViewSkin.class.getDeclaredMethod("resizeColumnToFitContent", TableColumn.class, int.class);
            columnToFitMethod.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void autoFitTable(TableView tableView) {
        tableView.getItems().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<?> c) {
                for (Object column : tableView.getColumns()) {
                    try {
                        columnToFitMethod.invoke(tableView.getSkin(), column, -1);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't find or import the class TableViewSkin. I'm using Java 8 and this class doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: It does not exist any more, this solution can't be used with the newer JAVA versions. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50583912/javafx-9-10-no-longer-possible-to-override-tableview-resizecolumntofitcontent

Comment: @MindaugasBernatavičius it's long time I have not dev JavaFX, but when that method is removed, is it able to double click the column divider to auto fit, if it is, we can find the method triggerred

Answer (score 3):

If you had 4 columns and only last column needed to expand to fill the rest of the table width and the other columns remained the size I set in Scene Builder.

```
double width = col1.widthProperty().get();
width += col2.widthProperty().get();
width += col3.widthProperty().get();

col4.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().subtract(width));
```

Or if you had 2 columns that needed to expand then.

```
double width = col1.widthProperty().get();
width += col3.widthProperty().get();

col2.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().subtract(width).divide(2));
col4.prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().subtract(width).divide(2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Also, a very simple trick based on an `AnchorPane` will be a good solution.

We gonna wrap the `TableView` into a `AnchorPane` but also we gonna anchor the left and right side of the `TableView` like this:

```
AnchorPane wrapper = new AnchorPane();

AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(table, 10.0);
AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(table, 10.0);
wrapper.getChildren().add(table);
```

This simple code will stretch the `TableView` in both directions (right and left) also, it will adjust whenever the scrollbar is added.

You can get an idea of how this works watching this animated gif.

[image]

Now you can resize the columns, adding these lines:

```
fnColumn.setMaxWidth( 1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 30 ); // 30% width
lnColumn.setMaxWidth( 1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 40 ); // 40% width
emColumn.setMaxWidth( 1f * Integer.MAX_VALUE * 30 ); // 30% width
```

Answer (score 0):

my idea.

```
table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>("Num") {
    {
        // 15%
        prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().multiply(0.15));
    }
});
table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>("Filename") {{
    // 20%
    prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().multiply(.2));
}});
table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>("Path") {{
    // 50%
    prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().multiply(.5));
}});
table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<>("Status") {
    {
        // 15%
        prefWidthProperty().bind(table.widthProperty().multiply(.15));
    }
});
```