# how to fix javafx - tableview size to current window size

Tags: javafx, tableview, autoresize

I'm totally new to standalone applications. Please any one help me on this.

I have TableView with 6 columns which is half showing in the window as shown below.

[image]

I want to fix its current window size, even when the window is expanded, the tableview should auto resize. Is there any way to do this?

**This Is The Code Snippet**

```
GridPane tableGrid= new GridPane();
tableGrid.setVgap(10);
tableGrid.setHgap(10);
Label schoolnameL= new Label(SCHOOL+school_id);
schoolnameL.setId("schoolLabel");
Button exportDataSheetBtn= new Button("Export In File");
tableView.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
tableGrid.getChildren().addAll(schoolnameL,exportDataSheetBtn,tableView);
```

Comment: Adding some code related to TableView and its parent container would help us help you better.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done by binding the preferred height and width to the height and width of the primary stage. Here's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MCVE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<ObservableList<String>>();

        // We bind the prefHeight- and prefWidthProperty to the height and width of the stage.
        table.prefHeightProperty().bind(stage.heightProperty());
        table.prefWidthProperty().bind(stage.widthProperty());

        stage.setScene(new Scene(table, 400, 400));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Create Tabel inside GridPane and Use GridePane inside AnchorPane.Click on GridPane(capture1).
[image]
Click on Ancho Pane Constraint inside the GridPane Layout (captur2).
[image]

In table view Layout select Hgrow and Vgrow as 'Always'(capture3)[image]

Comment: This worked for me - all I needed to do was to set Hgrow and Vgrow, thanks

Comment: works on ArchonePane as well

Answer (score 4):

```
VBox.setVgrow(tableView, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

OR for your parent layouts:

```
 VBox.setVgrow({{PARENT}}, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

It fixed for me:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ScrollPane as the root of the scene and put everything else inside it. Then set the property setFitToWidth and setFitToHeight to true and all the content inside the ScrollPane will be stretched to fit the ScrollPane size and the ScrollPane will fit the Scene since its a Layout Pane. It will also show ScrollBars if the user resizes the window to be smaller than the contents minWidth, so the content doesnt get cut off!

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    TableView<ObservableList<String>> table = new TableView<ObservableList<String>>();
    table.setMinWidth(400);

    ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(table);
    sp.setFitToHeight(true);
    sp.setFitToWidth(true);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(table, 800, 600));
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

I copied parts of the MCVE From Jonathan's answer, hope you dont mind Jonathan :)

For more general tips for making resizable GUIs check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10322519/4174072)!

Comment: more like a workaround than a fix