# How to make pane and elements in it resizable when stage size is changing

Tags: javafx

Can you please tell me how can I realize that the whole content of a pane will be resized while the stage is resized with mousedragg. Here is my code:

```
public class fab extends Application {
private Stage stage;
private Pane pane;
private Scene scene;


@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

this.stage = stage;

Button button = new Button("Button");

pane = new Pane();
pane.getChildren().add(button);

stage.setTitle("Test");
scene = new Scene(pane, 640, 640);
stage.setScene(scene);
stage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

I think there is the idea of binding. But I don't know how to use that, in order  to make all nodes of a pane resizable, when the stage size is changing.

I'm searching a solution without Fxml or sceneBuilder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what you expect this program to do vs what it currently does? And what isn't resizing properly?

Comment: @Matt I have edit my Code and made it shorter. The button inside of the screen should become bigger when I resize the window. But when I resize the window the button remain in his dimension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind stage resizing with resizing of components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318467/how-to-bind-stage-resizing-with-resizing-of-components)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution if you wish to bind the width of the button to you scene width

```
button.minWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
```

You can also modify this +/- whatever you want for ex

```
button.minWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(20));
```

and you can do the same for the height

```
button.minHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(200));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you insists to use the `Pane` container then  after the line `scene = new Scene(pane, 640, 640);`  add this:

```
scene.widthProperty().addListener((c,o,n)->button.setPrefWidth((Double)n));
scene.heightProperty().addListener((c,o,n)->button.setPrefHeight((Double)n));
```

and after the line `stage.setScene(scene);`  add this:

```
button.setPrefSize(scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight());
```

This works fine with `Pane` and do your required thing.

But I prefer using an `AnchorPane` container and set the Top, Right,Bottom and Left anchors to 0 .