# JavaFx 2 create TableView with single column

Tags: java, layout, tableview, javafx-2

I am trying to create a table with a single column using the following code :

```
TableView<String> table = new TableView<String>();
table.getColumns().clear();
table.getColumns().add(new TableColumn<String, String>("City Name"));
table.setItems(cityList);
```

However I get a table with the "City Name" column followed by a blank column

I am new to JavaFx so there might be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recall that tried to "remove" blank columns myself by playing with css properties in the past without luck. The workaround was either,
 - set the pref width of the `cityColumn` to cover whole space manually:

```
TableColumn<String, String> cityColumn = new TableColumn<String, String>("City Name");
cityColumn.setPrefWidth(table.getPrefWidth() - 2);
```

`-2` for border widths. Also you can bind column width property to table width property directly, resulting the col width is updated automatically when the table width is resized. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/10152992/682495.
Or,
 - set the column resize policy to `CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY`:

```
table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

Comment: CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY is all you need

Comment: Went for the CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY in the end.

Comment: For fxml: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14095708/fxml-set-tableview-column-resize-policy