# javafx: Multiple events in a setRowFactory and combining anonymous inner class and lambda expressions

Tags: java, javafx

I have 2 sets of events that change the appearance of the table row.

1. table flashing when some conditions flash
2. table highlighting when a new item is added

Suppose my `TableView` is called `table`, my code structure is like this:

```
TableView<Trade> table = ... ;
table.setRowFactory(            private final BooleanBinding itemIsNewTrade = Bindings.isNotNull(itemProperty()).and(Bindings.equal(itemProperty(), recentlyAddedTrade));

        {
            // anonymous constructor:
            itemIsNewTrade.addListener((obs, wasNew, isNew) -> pseudoClassStateChanged(newTradePseudoClass, isNew));
        }   

            tv -> {
            TableRow<Trade> row = new TableRow<>();
            Timeline flasher = new Timeline(

                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), e -> {
                        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, true);
                    }),

                    new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0), e -> {
                        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
                    })
            );
            flasher.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

            ChangeListener<Boolean> cautionListener = (obs, cautionWasSet, cautionIsNowSet) -> {
                if (cautionIsNowSet) {
                    flasher.play();
                } else {
                    flasher.stop();
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
                }
            };

            row.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                if (oldItem != null) {
                    oldItem.cautionProperty().removeListener(cautionListener);
                }
                if (newItem == null) {
                    flasher.stop();
                    row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
                } else {
                    newItem.cautionProperty().addListener(cautionListener);
                    if (newItem.cautionProperty().get()) {
                        flasher.play();
                    } else {
                        flasher.stop();
                        row.pseudoClassStateChanged(flashHighlight, false);
                    }
                }
            });
            return row ;
        }
    );
```

**UPDATE:**
The code for table flashing comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164454/javafx-table-row-flashing/32168257#32168257), while the code for table highlighting comes from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24166995/java-fx-8-table-row-highlighting). I tried to combine both together by having a structure like above.

But I am getting error. I just **do not know how to combine Anonymous inner class and lambda expression together**

How should I overcome this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to do this, is to create a separate `TableRow` class instead of an anonymous inner class.

I created an example implementation below.

Some things worth mentioning:

1. You need do define the style `.table-row-cell:new` in your CSS file for the newly added `TableRow`.
2. You need to define the style `.table-row-cell:flash` in your CSS file for the `TableRow`(s) which are currently flashing.
3. The constructor needs to know (`ObjectExpression`) where the recently added item is stored, which is probably `recentlyAddedTrade` in your case.
4. The constructor needs to know (`Function<T, BooleanExpression>`) how to extract the property determining the flashing state. In your case it should be `Trade::cautionProperty`.

Here is the example implementation:

```
public static class AnimatedTableRow<T> extends TableRow<T> {

    private static final PseudoClass PS_NEW = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("new");
    private static final PseudoClass PS_FLASH = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("flash");

    private final ObjectExpression<T> recentItem;
    private final InvalidationListener recentlyAddedListener = fObs -> recentItemChanged();

    private final Function<T, BooleanExpression> flashExtractor;
    private final ChangeListener<Boolean> flashListener = (fObs, fOld, fNew) -> flasherChanged(fNew);
    private final Timeline flashTimeline;

    public AnimatedTableRow(ObjectExpression<T> fRecentlyAddedProperty,
            Function<T, BooleanExpression> fFlashExtractor) {
        recentItem = fRecentlyAddedProperty;
        recentItem.addListener(new WeakInvalidationListener(recentlyAddedListener));

        flashExtractor = fFlashExtractor;
        flashTimeline = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(0.5), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_FLASH, true)),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1.0), e -> pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_FLASH, false)));
        flashTimeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
    }

    private void flasherChanged(boolean fNew) {
        if (fNew) {
            flashTimeline.play();
        } else {
            flashTimeline.stop();
            pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_FLASH, false);
        }
    }

    private void recentItemChanged() {
        final T tmpRecentItem = recentItem.get();
        pseudoClassStateChanged(PS_NEW, tmpRecentItem != null && tmpRecentItem == getItem());
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        if (getItem() != null) {
            final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply(getItem());
            if (be != null) {
                be.removeListener(flashListener);
            }
        }

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (getItem() != null) {
            final BooleanExpression be = flashExtractor.apply(getItem());
            if (be != null) {
                be.addListener(flashListener);
                flasherChanged(be.get());
            }
        }

        recentItemChanged();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
table.setRowFactory(tableView -> new AnimatedTableRow<>(recentlyAddedPerson, Person::flashProperty));
```

Comment: And how would I call this class in  `setRowFactory()` ?