# SimpleStringProperty and SimpleIntegerProperty TableView JavaFX

Tags: java, tableview, javafx

So i am trying to learn how to use JavaFx Tableview and i stumpled across this tutorial:

[Oracle tableview tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm)

in this tutorial they show that in order to fill you tableView you have to fill it with Strings, but not just any String you have to format you `String` to a `SimpleStringProperty`

i tried without the format and the result was that none of the information would show!

Also i found that if you want to add an `Integer` to the table you would have to declare it as an `SimpleIntegerProperty`

Now i am fairly new to JavaFx but does this mean that when i create an object i have to format all my Integers and Strings to be able to fill my TableView? it seems rather stupid but maybe there is a higher purpose? or is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: It's a badly written tutorial. They gloss over too many important points, for example Generics.

Comment: I agree those tutorials don't demonstrate a lot of features and topics.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't need to use Properties in your table data objects for them to display, although use of Properties in certain circumstances is desirable.

The following code will display a table of people based on a Person class which has only String fields.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ReadOnlyTableView extends Application {
  private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
  private final ObservableList<Person> data =
    FXCollections.observableArrayList(
      new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
      new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
      new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
      new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
      new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
    );

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(vbox)));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String email;

    private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
      this.firstName = fName;
      this.lastName = lName;
      this.email = email;
    }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String fName) { firstName = fName; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public void setLastName(String lName) { lastName = lName; }
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String inMail) { email = inMail; }
  }
}
```

*Explanation*

The purpose of using Properties and ObservableLists is that these are listenable elements. When properties are used, if the value of a property attribute in the datamodel changes, the view of the item in the TableView is automatically updated to match the updated datamodel value.  For example, if the value of a person's email property is set to a new value, that update will be reflected in the TableView because it listens for the property change.  If instead, a plain String had been used to represent the email, the TableView would not refresh as it would be unaware of email value changes.

The [PropertyValueFactory](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/cell/PropertyValueFactory.html) documentation describes this process in detail:

> An example of how to use this class is:
>
> ```
> TableColumn<Person,String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person,String>("First Name");
> firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person,String>("firstName"));
> ```
>
> In this example, the "firstName" string is used as a reference to an
>   assumed firstNameProperty() method in the Person class type (which is
>   the class type of the TableView items list). Additionally, this method
>   must return a Property instance. If a method meeting these
>   requirements is found, then the TableCell is populated with this
>   ObservableValue. In addition, the TableView will automatically add an
>   observer to the returned value, such that any changes fired will be
>   observed by the TableView, resulting in the cell immediately updating.
>
> If no method matching this pattern exists, there is fall-through
>   support for attempting to call get() or is() (that
>   is, getFirstName() or isFirstName() in the example above). If a method
>   matching this pattern exists, the value returned from this method is
>   wrapped in a ReadOnlyObjectWrapper and returned to the TableCell.
>   However, in this situation, this means that the TableCell will not be
>   able to observe the ObservableValue for changes (as is the case in the
>   first approach above).

**Update**

Here is a contrasting example to the first example which demonstrates how a TableView can observe and automatically refresh based on changes to it's ObservableList of items and changes to the value of a property based item attribute.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PropertyBasedTableView extends Application {
  private TableView<Person> table = new TableView<Person>();
  private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
  private void initData() {
    data.setAll(
      new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
      new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
      new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
      new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
      new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com")
    );
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
    initData();

    stage.setTitle("Table View Sample");
    stage.setWidth(450);
    stage.setHeight(500);

    final Label label = new Label("Address Book");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    TableColumn firstNameCol = new TableColumn("First Name");
    firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));

    TableColumn lastNameCol = new TableColumn("Last Name");
    lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
    lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

    TableColumn emailCol = new TableColumn("Email");
    emailCol.setMinWidth(200);
    emailCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("email"));

    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, emailCol);
    table.setPrefHeight(300);

    final Button setEmailButton = new Button("Set first email in table to wizard@frobozz.com");
    setEmailButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (data.size() > 0) {
          data.get(0).setEmail("wizard@frobozz.com");
        }  
      }
    });

    final Button removeRowButton = new Button("Remove first row from the table");
    removeRowButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if (data.size() > 0) {
          data.remove(0);
        }  
      }
    });

    final Button resetButton = new Button("Reset table data");
    resetButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        initData();
      }
    });

    final VBox vbox = new VBox(10);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, setEmailButton, removeRowButton, resetButton);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(vbox)));
    stage.show();
  }

  public static class Person {
    private final StringProperty firstName;
    private final StringProperty lastName;
    private final StringProperty email;

    private Person(String fName, String lName, String email) {
      this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
      this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
      this.email = new SimpleStringProperty(email);
    }

    public String getFirstName() { return firstName.get(); }
    public void setFirstName(String fName) { firstName.set(fName); }
    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() { return firstName; }
    public String getLastName() { return lastName.get(); }
    public void setLastName(String lName) { lastName.set(lName); }
    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() { return lastName; }
    public String getEmail() { return email.get(); }
    public void setEmail(String inMail) { email.set(inMail); }
    public StringProperty emailProperty() { return email; }  // if this method is commented out then the tableview will not refresh when the email is set.
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your response if i could i would have given you more than 1 thumbs up :) 

2ndly so what your saying is that by converting the Strings to a SimpleStringProperty the table will automaticly update? And by choosing not to you would have to update the table manuelly?

Comment: Added a quote from the PropertyValueFactory to the answer to address Marc's additional question.

Comment: will the table update automaticly when one of the propertys are changed and if so how do you do it? do you change the list or the set the value using object.setName() (as an example)

Comment: Added a further example to demonstrate how to get a table to update automatically when a property value is changed or the list backing the tableview is modified.

Comment: You sir! You deserve a medal thank you for putting up with me!

one last thing though why is the class person static

Comment: For the example provided, use of the static qualifier on the person class is superfluous; i.e. it will work with or without that qualifier.  See the [nested classes tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) to understand what a static nested class does.

Comment: i can see that you use public StringProperty emailProperty() is this always nesseary? or can you do it with the simple getEmail() ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19553/discussion-between-jewelsea-and-marc-rasmussen)

Comment: Do the accessors have to end in the word property? It seems absurd that we must change our model objects to suit our view objects requirements. Is there a way to do this without changing already built model objects with typical getX and setX methods?

Comment: Figured it out, just a point that I  found out the PropertyValueFactory is picky with case.  For example if my accessor is called  getLastName(), then in the PropertyFactory I can use lastName or LastName but not lastname.  When I had an accessor called getlastName, it did not seem to like that either because of the lower case L on last.

Comment: @AndrewS it's required naming convention as described in JavaBeans. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#sthref8 in this link go to 'Understanding Property'