# Java FXML :How to TableCell Edit Column Then reflect to second Column

Tags: java, fxml

Price: 150;
       Quantity : 4;
        total Price :600; 
 Then I am Quantity Change then Reflect to the Total Price.  

       How To Solve It?

Comment: Too difficult to answer

Comment: Use setDisable(true); setDisable(false); so it refresh the table and your data should be updated...

Comment: Thanks Its Work Properly but Can U give Other soluations which Is Optimize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`USe SimpleIntegerProperty.`

Check it out example How it works...

1) [SimpleStringProperty and SimpleIntegerProperty TableView JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381067/simplestringproperty-and-simpleintegerproperty-tableview-javafx)

2) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JavaFX/DisplayJavaFXbeaninaTableView.htm