# Extra elements in table are always visible, even without underlying data

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

Here is my problem. I have table with normal text columns and 2 columns with dropdowns and one with checkboxes. This is my callback for cell factory for dropdown columns :

```
     Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>> dropdownConditionCellFactory =
                   new Callback<TableColumn<Person, String>, TableCell<Person, String>>() {
               @Override
               public TableCell call(TableColumn p) {
                 Tools.Tables.ComboBoxCell<partCondition> cell = new  Tools.Tables.ComboBoxCell<partCondition>(partConditionList)

                   return cell;
               }
           };
```

And class for this cell factory:

public static class ComboBoxCell extends TableCell {

```
    private ComboBox combo;

    public ComboBoxCell() {
        combo = new ComboBox();
        setGraphic(combo);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

    }

    public ComboBoxCell(ObservableList items) {
        combo = new ComboBox();
        combo.setItems(items);
        setGraphic(combo);
        setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        combo.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }

    public T getSelectedItem()
    {
        return (T) combo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    }

    public void setSelectedItem(T t)
    {
        combo.getSelectionModel().select(t);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when Table is quite big and there is only 2 rows in it, dropdowns are produced anyway and it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way to produce only as many dropdowns and checkboxes as many items there is in observable list that feeds this table?

Answer (score 1):

While working with cells, please read the [Cell API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html) beforehand, to understand how they are handled under the hood. In short the cells are reused in different rows to render different items/records. Each time when the cell is reused its `updateItem()` method will be called to refresh the item the cell is rendering. Thus you need to override this method and control the `graphic` in there, instead of in constructor:

```
    private ComboBox combo;

    public ComboBoxCell() {
        combo = new ComboBox();
    }

    public ComboBoxCell(ObservableList items) {
        combo = new ComboBox();
        combo.setItems(items);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            combo.getSelectionModel().select(item);
            setGraphic(combo);
            setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This method works perfectly, unless the list is very long. Then elements start to dissapear randomly (Famous Javafx tableview problem, discussed here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469661/textfield-inside-tableview-gone-after-scroll-javafx/18019529#18019529 )

Maybe there is another way around this problem, perhaps with CSS?