# Validation of editable cell in onEditCommit in TableColumn

Tags: java, validation, javafx-2, tablecolumn

I'm writing editable table with JavaFX I want to validate input (e.g. whether same value already exists in table/column) if validation fails I want reject new value. In other words when user types new value into cell and hits ENTER, I do my validation and if it fails I want to see in cell old value.

My code looks very similar to this example
http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/04/javafx-2-editable-tableview.html

I thought that I could do something like that

```
colName.setCellFactory(trainerStringCellFactory);
colName.setOnEditCommit(
  new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<GymTrainer, String>>() {
    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<GymTrainer, String> t) {
       GymTrainer newTrainer = new GymTrainer(t.getNewValue(), trainer.getSurrname(), trainer.getRateOfPay());
       newTrainer.setTrainerId(trainer.getTrainerId());
   if ( !updateTrainer(newTrainer) ) {
          // Here I would like to replace value in editable cell
       }
     }
   }
 });
```

Does anyone has an idea how to do that, or maybe it is wrong place to do so?

Answer (score 2):

After few days I found way how to deal with this problem. First thing is that if you don't update data associated with row in TableView (in my case it was GymTrainer) then after starting app once again old value was shown, so thing I had to do was to refresh TableColumn so real values from 
GymTrainer instance is displayed.

I did it using workaround from this post: [JavaFX 2.1 TableView refresh items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065140/javafx-2-1-tableview-refresh-items)

Code will look like that:

```
colName.setCellFactory(trainerStringCellFactory);
colName.setOnEditCommit(
  new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<GymTrainer, String>>() {
    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<GymTrainer, String> t) {
       GymTrainer newTrainer = new GymTrainer(t.getNewValue(), trainer.getSurrname(), trainer.getRateOfPay());
       newTrainer.setTrainerId(trainer.getTrainerId());
       if ( !updateTrainer(newTrainer) ) {
         tblTrainers.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
         tblTrainers.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
       }
    }
  }
 });
```

Maybe it will help somebody.