# How to refresh data from database in javafx TableView?

Tags: hibernate, javafx

In my application I hava TableView which I'm using to show data from database recieved via Hibernate sql query and then converted to FX ObservableList

```
planningData = FXCollections.observableArrayList((List<Object[]>) service.getPlanningTableData(from, to));
```

What I'm trying to do is to smoothly update content of my TableView each 30 sec.
Right now I'm just recalling my database method and setting items in tableView like this:

```
tableView.setItems(planningData)
```

But this is useless.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065140/javafx-2-1-tableview-refresh-items

Comment: tableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
tableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);

Comment: This is not really what I'm looking for. I changing whole table data and this is costing me table content blink

Answer (score 0):

i was having the same problem but simply creating a new database connection to pull the data to populate the tableview worked. But make sure to close the connection so that you wont have a bunch of connections lying there without use.