# Possible ways to refresh tableview in Javafx

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

[The one in the picture is what i need , whenever I press sell button the quatity in the backgroud tableview column should change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFjyZ.png)  What makes tableview refreshed automatically detecting the change in database value without running the program from scratch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2.1 TableView refresh items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065140/javafx-2-1-tableview-refresh-items)

Comment: A `TableView` will automatically update when you change the data in its `items` list. You need to make your question more specific if you have code that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

you attached an observableList to the Tableview, so it inmediatly detects any change and update the view. So, the thing here is you have to maintain updated your observableList, you should find a way to detects change in you database. If you database is only modified for you application this should not be a hard task to complete, on the other hand, if it's modified for another system I suppossed you have to maintain the list consulting the database every often.