# TableView ListChangeListener may return incorrect list index

Tags: java, javafx

In a TableView I encountered this strange situation:

- click a row -> one item selected
- shift+click the row below -> two items selected
- click the lower of the two rows to single-select it -> call to `.getList()` returns -1, but second call returns correct index

EDIT:
This is a bug, it can be tracked at http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8147820
It was reported for 1.8u60, still there in 1.8u101

```
@FXML TableView <TableDataRow> table;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

    table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends Integer> c) {
            System.out.print(c.getList()); //sometimes returns [-1]
            System.out.println(c.getList()); //returns correct selection indices
        }
    });
```

Comment: What does click that row again mean..

Comment: hope it's more precise now

Comment: Definetly a bug... `c.getList` should return the underlying list and this should not be modified during the invokation of this listener.

Comment: Try out `List<? extends Integer> lst = c.getList();
                System.out.println(lst.get(0));
                System.out.println(lst.get(0));`. Sometimes this prints different values which shouldn't happen. Reading shouldn't modify the list... Nor should the list be modified concurrently...

Comment: Well then... great, yet another bug in TableView.
I also came across the "screen not updating problem" already covered in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065140/javafx-2-1-tableview-refresh-items)