# JavaFx Tableview refresh() method alternative

Tags: java-8, javafx-8

I have one issue with my application which is solved using `refresh()` method of `TableView`. But this method is available since **JavaFX 8u60**. Our production environment uses build version prior to that. Can anyone let me know which method should I use in prior versions?

Comment: Why can't you upgrade? Different updates of the same Java major version should be backwards-compatible.  
To answer the question - you can hide and show any column, which should have a similar effect to calling `TableView::refresh`.

Comment: I tried using the below mentioned code but it doesn't seem to work.

for(int i=0 ; i<table.getColumns().size() ; i++) {
   table.getColumns().get(i).setVisible(false);
   table.getColumns().get(i).setVisible(true);
  }

Comment: The application is very old and it is huge. So upgrade may cost a fortune.

Comment: Upgrading from java 8 update X to java 8 update Y > X???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2.1 TableView refresh items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065140/javafx-2-1-tableview-refresh-items)

Comment: I tried the above link as well but it didn't work. The problem I am facing is I am seeing duplicate records in my Table even though I am using table.getItems().clear(); followed by table.getItems().addAll(...). I am not sure why it is not clearing those or what kind of cache it is keeing it.

Comment: So recreating or re-rendering the rows in the table helps me solve this probem. refresh() method does it.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] - it is possible there is a problem somewhere else in the code, i.e. a problematic implementation of a cell/cell factory etc., but it is impossible to tell without a code reproducing the problem.

Comment: The issue got solved by using the body of refresh() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using the body of refresh() method. I was unable to use refresh() method in prior versions to mentioned version as the method was private. So I used the body of refresh() instead of refresh().

```
table.getProperties().put(TableViewSkinBase.RECREATE, Boolean.TRUE);
```