# TableView has more columns than specified

Tags: layout, tableview, javafx-2

When using a TableView in JavaFX 2, there seems to be magically one column added instead of resizing the existing ones. Please see the following screenshot.

What I would expect/want: Both column shall have 50% of space, no third (unnamed/empty) column shall be added.

[image]

Created using Scene Builder, FXML code:

```
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>

<BorderPane id="BorderPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
  <top>
    <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
      <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
      </columns>
    </TableView>
  </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/q/11033404/682495](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11033404/682495)

Comment: Thanks Uluk, that helped! Please post as answer, so I can select it as the correct one :-) Do you have any idea for this strange behaviour?

Comment: This happens because default column width behavior adjust column to widest element in the column. Thus empty space left not used.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use

```
table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

By doing this you ensure that the extra space in table column header will be distributed among the columns. In this distribution the columns' max and min widths are taken into account of course.
By default the `TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY` is used where the tablecolumns will take their preferred width initially.

Comment: Can you do it  in FXML too?

Comment: @user3111525, yes. Try as `<TableView columnResizePolicy = "CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"  ... >`. It should work, though didn't try.

Comment: Is it possible to use preferred width but don't show that additional column at the right? Like combine UNCONSTRAINED with CONSTRAINED policy.

Answer (score 4):

Uluk Bly's answer is absolutely correct for the code.

Additionally, using Scenebuilder, make sure to set the policy in the Properties dropdown window to the same (CONSTRAINED), and it should show up in your FXML file like so:

```
    <columnResizePolicy>
    <TableView fx:constant = "CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY"/>
    </columnResizePolicy>
```

Comment: Note this should go inside the `<TableView>` element.