# JavaFX misaligned header on TableView or extra column

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

[Pic of the TableView header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwFzj.png)

I need help aligning the headers for the columns on this TableView. The problem seems to be related to setting the TableView's column resize policy to constrained-resize. Can someone explain how to fix this? Thanks.

I am setting the policy to constrained-resize to get rid of the extra column based on this SO post: [TableView has more columns than specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933918/tableview-has-more-columns-than-specified)

My stack: Java 8, JavaFX 8, and scenebuilder

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="200.0" maxWidth="322.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="320.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <center>
      <TableView fx:id="statusTable" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="322.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="statusDescription" minWidth="120.0" prefWidth="210.0" text="Description" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="status" prefWidth="97.0" text="Priority" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Can you post some code in the form of a [MCVE] showing how you got this?

Comment: I can add the fxml now, but it will take sometime for me to recreate the java code.