# JavaFX: Cell renderer instance for a given row of a TableColumn

Tags: tableview, javafx, tablecolumn

In JavaFX, how to get the cell renderer instance for a given cell of a given TableColumn?

In Swing, the way to do it would be to invoke **getTableCellRendererComponent()** on the **TableCellRenderer** for that column and pass it the row and column indices.  But JavaFX seems to be very different.  I tried searching and going through the TableColumn API but I don't seem to be able to figure this out.  Maybe I have to do something with **getCellFactory()**.

My goal is to query the preferred width for each cell renderer of a column and then calculate the width to set on the column so that the contents of all the cells of that column are fully visible.

A question was asked here - [JavaFX 2 Automatic Column Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152828/javafx-2-automatic-column-width) - where the goal of the original poster was the same as that of mine.  But there hasn't been a satisfactory answer there yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is resizeToFit() method in TableColumnHeader class. Unfortunately it is protected. How about just copy-paste the code to your application and change it a bit:

```
protected void resizeToFit(TableColumn col, int maxRows) {
    List<?> items = tblView.getItems();
    if (items == null || items.isEmpty()) return;

    Callback cellFactory = col.getCellFactory();
    if (cellFactory == null) return;

    TableCell cell = (TableCell) cellFactory.call(col);
    if (cell == null) return;

    // set this property to tell the TableCell we want to know its actual
    // preferred width, not the width of the associated TableColumn
    cell.getProperties().put("deferToParentPrefWidth", Boolean.TRUE);//the change is here, only the first parameter, since the original constant is not accessible outside package

    // determine cell padding
    double padding = 10;
    Node n = cell.getSkin() == null ? null : cell.getSkin().getNode();
    if (n instanceof Region) {
        Region r = (Region) n;
        padding = r.getInsets().getLeft() + r.getInsets().getRight();
    } 

    int rows = maxRows == -1 ? items.size() : Math.min(items.size(), maxRows);
    double maxWidth = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        cell.updateTableColumn(col);
        cell.updateTableView(tblView);
        cell.updateIndex(row);

        if ((cell.getText() != null && !cell.getText().isEmpty()) || cell.getGraphic() != null) {
            getChildren().add(cell);
            cell.impl_processCSS(false);
            maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, cell.prefWidth(-1));
            getChildren().remove(cell);
        }
    }

    col.impl_setWidth(maxWidth + padding);
}
```

Then you can call the method after load data:

```
for (TableColumn clm : tblView.getColumns()) {
    resizeToFit(clm, -1);
}
```