# Where JavaFX TableView width comes from?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

It looks like `TableView` has some default width, independent from columns content (not to mention height and position on screen, which also are affected by using it as a *root* of `Scene` instead of for example StackPane).

I understand that every *JavaFX* element has it's **preferred size**, and that scene is adjusting to it, but I wonder **where** this **comes from**? I tried to find it in `TableView` documentation and get it's width using getters, but with no success.

I know I can set stage width and height explicitly, but it's not what I am interested in.

On this example you can observe how the size (and position) of the window change, depending of it's content.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    TableView table = createTable();
    StackPane pane = new StackPane();

    Scene scene = new Scene(table);
//  Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: It's retrieved using the `prefWidth` property. In this there's probably some logic in the `TableViewSkin` class involved...

Comment: @fabian but then do you know why *getPrefWidth()* on this `TableView` returns -1?

Comment: A pref width/height of `-1` is the value of `Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`. This means the preferred size is computed during layout, using methods like `computePrefWidth`. As `TableView` is a `Control`, the implementation of this computation is likely in the skin class instead of the control class. If you're wondering how to _get_ this computed value, I'm not sure you can—at least not reliably. There's `Node#prefWidth(double)` but you need to know what the parent passes as the height value if the node uses it for computations.

Comment: @Slaw yay, I really get it now, thanks to you. actually, with those informations and a little digging, it was not so hard to find it. if anyone is wondering about the same thing, take a look at `computePrefHeight(double width, double topInset, double rightInset, double bottomInset, double leftInset)` in `TableViewSkinBase` - the implementation is really funny ;) (I'm using JavaFX 12). @Slaw, please add your comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it comes to minimum, preferred, and maximum dimensions of a [`Region`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html), there are three different modes<sup>1</sup>:

1. The developer sets them explicitly (e.g. `setPrefWidth(400)`).
2. They are set to [`Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#USE_COMPUTED_SIZE) (i.e. `-1.0`)<sup>2</sup>.
3. They are set to [`Region.USE_PREF_SIZE`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#USE_PREF_SIZE) (i.e. negative infinity)<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1. The preferred dimensions only have two modes as `USE_PREF_SIZE` only has meaning for the minimum and maximum dimensions.</sup>
<sup>2. This is the default for `Region` and most (all?) of its subclasses.</sup>

---

When the dimensions are set to `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE` this means the values are computed during layout, using protected methods such as:

- [`Parent.computePrefWidth(double)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Parent.html#computePrefWidth(double))
- [`Parent.computePrefHeight(double)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Parent.html#computePrefHeight(double))

And similar methods for the minimum and maximum dimensions.

When it comes to `Control`s, however, these computations are typically delegated to the skin class. Most skin implementations inherit from [`SkinBase`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SkinBase.html) which provides similar methods for computing min/pref/max dimensions; they have the same names but accept more parameters to make the computations a little easier. You note in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56508235/where-javafx-tableview-width-comes-from#comment99605383_56508235) that, in the case of `TableView`, the computations for preferred width and height take place in [`TableViewSkinBase`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/skin/TableViewSkinBase.html).

You may be wondering how you can get this computed value; I don't believe you can in a reliable fashion. You could try using the public methods of `Node`, such as [`Node.prefWidth(double)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#prefWidth(double)), but the problem is knowing what value to pass as an argument. In the case the value shouldn't be `-1` then it's really only the parent that knows for certain how much space is available.

*Note: These methods of `Node` (e.g. `prefWidth(double)`) are the "entry point" for getting the minimum, preferred, and maximum dimensions of a `Node`. However, the `min`, `pref`, and `max` properties are not universal (available for `Region`s and, to an extent, `WebView`) and the `computeXXX` methods are unique to `Parent` (and its subclasses). Other kinds of `Node`s, such as `Shape`s, provide their own internal mechanisms.*

Also, the preferred dimensions are just a guideline. The parent is free to size its children as it sees fit within the constraints of the min and max values. If you want to know what the dimensions of a node ultimately end up being you can use the `Region.width` and `Region.height` properties (when using a `Region`) or the `Node.boundsInLocal` property (for an arbitrary `Node`). `WebView` and some `Shape` implementations also provide properties for knowing their dimensions.

---

***Note:***

*This answer focuses on `Node`s (i.e. the scene graph). As pointed out by kleopatra, other objects (e.g. `TableColumnBase`) that have properties like `prefWidth` don't have the same specified behavior as `Region`. For instance, setting the value to `-1` is not defined to behave the same way. This also applies to `WebView` which, while having min/pref/max dimension properties, is not a `Region`.*

*The `TableView`'s default skin implementation takes into account the `prefWidth` of each visible `TableColumn` when computing its preferred width.*

Comment: *cough (nothing new to you, obviously, just to nitpick <g>) ... TableColumn is _not_ a Node - or in other words: the effect of -1 for pref is unspecified ;)

Comment: True, though the question (as I interpreted it) was about `TableView` and my answer focuses on `Node`s only. I added a note about `TableColumnBase`.

Comment: oops ... looks like I misread the question, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: @Slaw "The TableView's default skin implementation takes into account the prefWidth of each visible TableColumn when computing its preferred width." - I see that. is there a way to affect those columns widths so they take into account table content? the problem which I have is preferred size is 80 (default), but during displaying they are wider (*width* property is much bigger).

Comment: @Line If you're asking if each `TableColumn` can automatically size itself to fit the largest of its content, the answer is probably "no". The problem is that only a small portion of the items are rendered and the table has no idea how much space the non-rendered items require. However, something in this question may provide an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650787/javafx-column-in-tableview-auto-fit-size

Comment: @Slaw the problem is they are resizing, but somehow after columns (and therefore table) size is calculated - that, connected with the fact that my scene is fitting to the table, results in clipped table - it's width is fixed to 400, and I can scroll the table inside.

Comment: @Line I'm not sure I understand the problem. Perhaps you should ask a new question where you can provide a [mre] and a more detailed explanation.