# JavaFx: Checkbox unwanted "background"

Tags: javafx, checkbox, javafx-8

I am looking for to remove the background of a checkbox because it takes space in a `TableCell` and it causes that the `CheckBox` is not centered.

As you can see if the background is marked red, it exceeds the checkbox and takes space.

Here is a minimal code you can verify it and the screenshoot:

Controller:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Object,String> one;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Object> table;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        one.setCellFactory(cell -> new CheckBoxTableCell<Object, String>(){
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if(empty){
                    return;
                }
                CheckBox graphic = (CheckBox) getGraphic();
                graphic.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");
            }
        });
        table.getItems().add(new Object());
    }
}
```

[image]

I would like to eliminate the red part so only keeping the box itself.

I tried to reset the padding for it but it doesn't work. Can you help me?

**Note: I won't accept `setPadding(new Insets(0,-x,-y,0)` so setting negative values to it to compensate the "error" only in that case if you can explain it why it is the only solution.**

Comment: if I understand this correctly you want to center it then try wrapping it in a `HBox` or `VBox` that will be centering it

Comment: Yes and no, I want to remove that red part of the checkbox.

Comment: so it should fill the complete height and width

Comment: No...I don't want to fill the cell's height and width, just i don't want the red part which is the background of the `CheckBox`.

Comment: so you want the cell by minimized to fit the checkbox perfectly then see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650787/javafx-column-in-tableview-auto-fit-size)

Comment: No... Please read the question again carefully and don't try to give me random answers, which won't help.

Comment: Note: For simply calling `#setStyle(String)` there's no need to cast to `CheckBox`.

Comment: @Slaw Yeah, i know that, i just wanted to see the methods which the `CheckBox` has, maybe I can find something to remove the unwanted background, but I couldn't and I didn't change it back. But its a good point ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space(~1px) to the bottom is from the "padding" property and the space(~5px) to the right is from the label-padding property. So if you turn off the both, then you can get rid of the background.

```
CheckBox graphic = (CheckBox) getGraphic();
graphic.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;-fx-label-padding:0px;-fx-padding:0px;");
```

Comment: [_same note_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59826601/javafx-checkbox-unwanted-background#comment105804287_59826601)