# How to fill available tableview width with columns?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

When tableview is created, the default behaviour of columns is to leave a lot of empty space. Is there a way to automatically fill the space?

One solution is described here:
[JavaFX 2 Automatic Column Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152828/javafx-2-automatic-column-width)
but this seems a little cumbersome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TornadoFX comes with an advanced column resize policy called `SmartResize`. You assign it to a TableView like this:

```
columnResizePolicy = SmartResize.POLICY
```

By default it tries to do something useful depending on the data, and it will assign any left over width to the last column.

You can configure resizing options per column by calling the appropriate configurator function. For example, to tell the policy to give remaining width to a given column:

```
column("Name", Person::nameProperty).remainingWidth()
```

You can configure multiple columns to receive remaning width, so that they will share the remaining width between them.

`contentWidth()` will make sure the column width fits the content, with optional additional padding: `contentWidth(padding = 50.0)`.

Most resize options also take an optional `useAsMin` parameter which will enforce the given setting as a minimum width for the column. `useAsMax` does the same for max width. You will get a fixed size by setting both `useAsMin` and `useAsMax` or specifying the `fixedWidth(width)` option.

You can distribute space using the `weigthedWidth(weightNum)` function, or even the `pctWidth(pctNum)` function. All these modes can be combined

Please see the [TornadoFX Guide chapter about the resize policy](https://edvin.gitbooks.io/tornadofx-guide/content/Appendix%20A%20-%20Supplementary%20Topics.html#a2---tableview-advanced-column-resizing) for more information:

Comment: Thats more then I expected :D Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome :) It probably hasn't seen wide spread usage yet, so please let me know if you run into any issues.

Comment: How do you use it from Java/Sacla?

Comment: TornadoFX is made for use with Kotlin only, although some functions can be called from other JVM languages as well. It's possible to call these functions, but it would be cumbersome and look weird.